# How to sort an array of linked list nodes from high to low(based on float value)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, linked-list

I have an array of linked list nodes which correspond to a course a student is enrolled in, and I need to sort the grades from highest to lowest. I've spent the entire day trying different sorting algorithms but I can't seem to get it to work properly. Admittedly, i'm not very good at sorting algorithms but it has not been for a lack of trying. I first tried `mergesort` which failed miserably, and my latest efforts haven't worked, either. Since it is an array of linked list nodes, i'm confused on how to implement the sorting because most algorithms target arrays or linked lists, not both.

Issues I've had:

1.) Duplicate nodes being displayed after multiple insertions

2.) Swapping grade values between nodes instead of swapping the nodes themselves

3.) No data being displayed at all.

If someone could point me in the right direction or help explain how to sort my nodes properly, I would be sincerely grateful. I've done hours of reading without any success.

The nodes link fine and display fine when I don't sort them, so I know that functionality is working ok. My class `Course()` uses a wrapper class `AGradeListNode()` to hold the data needed for node insertion into the array. Included in my code is my most recent attempt to sort the nodes (which does not work, causing duplicates). Please don't yell at me, i'm honestly trying to learn...

```
public class Course implements Serializable
{
    private String courseName;
    private String classTime;
    private int courseID;
    private Instructor instructor;
    private int numStudents;                     //variable for number of students in the list
    private int hold;                           //used to hold location of node
    protected static final int NUL = -1;        //Constant class var for end of list symbol.
    protected int currentPos;                   //Current position for iteration
    protected int list;                         //Reference to the first node on the list
    protected int free;                         //Reference to the first node on the free list
    protected AGradeListNode[] nodes;           // Array of AListNode holds the linked list

    // set by find method
    protected boolean found;                    // true if element found, else false
    protected int location;                     // node containing element, if found
    protected int previous;                     // node preceding location

    //wrapper class to create nodes for linked list array
    protected class AGradeListNode
    {
        private float grade;
        private Student student;
        private int next;                       //a link to the next node in linked list array

        //displays nodes as neatly formatted string
        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "Student: " + student.getLastName() + ", " + student.getFirstName() + "\n" +
                   "Grade: " + grade + "\n";
        }
    }
//constructor initializes array of nodes with 2 lists: used and free. 
    //contains other data needed for Course object instantiation as well
    public Course(int maxNumStudents, String courseName, String classTime, int courseID, Instructor instructor)
    {
        nodes = new AGradeListNode[maxNumStudents];

        for (int i = 0; i < maxNumStudents; i++)
        {
            nodes[i] = new AGradeListNode();
        }

        //link together the free nodes
        for (int i = 1; i < maxNumStudents; i++)
        {
            nodes[i - 1].next = i;
        }

        nodes[maxNumStudents - 1].next = NUL;

        list = NUL;
        free = 0;
        numStudents = 0;
        currentPos = NUL;

        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.classTime = classTime;
        this.courseID = courseID;
        this.instructor = instructor;
    }
// Returns the index of the next available node from the free list
    // and updates the free list index
    protected int getNode()
    {
        hold = free;
        free = nodes[free].next;
        return hold;
    }

    //Frees the node at array position index by linking it into the
    //free list
    protected void freeNode(int index)
    {
        nodes[index].next = free;
        free = index;
    }
//here is where im having issues. I'm attempting to sort the nodes based on
    //grade from high to low. Each grade belongs to a specific student object
    public void addStudentGrade(Student stu, float grade)
    {
        if (isFull())
        {
            return;
        }

        int newNode = getNode();
        nodes[newNode].student = stu;
        nodes[newNode].grade = grade;
        nodes[newNode].next = list;
        list = newNode;
        numStudents++;

        //sorting list, not working :/
        for (int j = 1; j <= numStudents; j++)
        {
            float hold = nodes[j].grade;
            int i = j-1;
            while ((i > -1) && (nodes[i].grade > hold))
            {
                nodes[i+1] = nodes[i];
                i--;
            }
            nodes[i+1] = nodes[j];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(nodes[i].toString());
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Here is my updated `addStudentGrade(Student stu, float grade)` method based on the great input from Andreas. My list still is not sorting correctly, though. The grades are sorted based on the order they are inputted rather than descending/ascending order (either works fine for me honestly, I just want the list to be sorted :/ ). If anyone can spot what i'm doing wrong and help me, I would be so grateful. I've been tinkering with this method for 3 days now, and i'm beginning to get quite discouraged:

```
//Method used to add student grades to nodes array. After LL node
    //is added, method sorts the used nodes in descending order based
    //off the float value grade
    public void addStudentGrade(Student stu, float grade)
    {
        if (isFull())
        {
            return;
        }

        int newNode = getNode();
        nodes[newNode].student = stu;
        nodes[newNode].grade = grade;
        nodes[newNode].next = list;
        list = newNode;
        numStudents++;

        //storing used nodes in temp Integer array
        Integer[] usedNodes = new Integer[numStudents];

        for (int i = list, j = 0; i != NUL; i = nodes[i].next)
        {
            usedNodes[j++] = i;
        }

        //sorting the temp array using lambda expression and 
        //Arrays.sort. I believe this is where my mistake is
        Arrays.sort(usedNodes, (i1, i2) ->
        {
            return Float.compare(nodes[i2].grade, nodes[i1].grade);
        });

        //rebuilding the linked list after sorting
        list = usedNodes[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < usedNodes.length; i++)
        {
            nodes[usedNodes[i-1]].next = usedNodes[i];
        }

        //printing the nodes to console for verification
        nodes[usedNodes[usedNodes.length - 1]].next = NUL;

        for (int i = 0; i <= numStudents; i++)
        {
            if (nodes[i].student != null)
            {
                System.out.println(nodes[i].toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

FINAL EDIT: Here is my complete, functioning class with included methods not posted in my original code(i've included additional methods to remove, replace and retrieve student grades, in hopes that it might help someone else in the future). It now sorts like it should(descending order) and instead of sorting at insertion, I sort the list during the call to the `printData()` method. I give much thanks to Andreas for helping me solve this task, I couldn't have done it without you! (at least in the specified time range needed):

```
// Returns the index of the next available node from the free list
    // and updates the free list index
    protected int getNode()
    {
        hold = free;
        free = nodes[free].next;
        return hold;
    }

    //Frees the node at array position index by linking it into the
    //free list
    protected void freeNode(int index)
    {
        nodes[index].next = free;
        free = index;
        nodes[free].student = null;
    }

    private void find(int id)
    {
        found = false;
        current = list;
        previous = NUL;
        while (!found || current != NUL )
        {
            if (nodes[current].student.getId() == id)
            {
                found = true;
                location = current;
                return;
            }
            previous = current;
            current = nodes[current].next;
        }
    }

    //Method used to add student grades to nodes array. After LL node
    //is added, method sorts the used nodes in descending order based
    //off the float value grade
    public void addStudentGrade(Student stu, float grade)
    {
        if (isFull())
        {
            return;
        }

        int newNode = getNode();
        nodes[newNode].student = stu;
        nodes[newNode].grade = grade;
        nodes[newNode].next = list;
        list = newNode;
        numStudents++;

        //printing sorted data to console
        printData();
    }

    public boolean removeStudentGrade(int id)
    {
        find(id);
        if (found)
        {
            hold = location;
            if (list == location)
            {
                list = nodes[list].next;   // remove first node
                System.out.println("Removing first node");
            }
            else
            {
                nodes[previous].next = nodes[location].next;
            }
            freeNode(hold);
            numStudents--;
        }
        return found;
    }

    //updates student grade from nodes array based on student id
    public void updateStudentGrade(int id, float newGrade)
    {
        find(id);
        if (found)
        {
            hold = location;
            nodes[hold].grade = newGrade;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Student ID not found. Please check data entry and try again.");
        }
    }

    //Method that searches array for student by id #. if found,
    //students grade is returned. if not, -1 is returned
    public float findStudentGrade(int id)
    {
        find(id);
        if (found)
        {
            hold = location;
            return nodes[hold].grade;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Student ID not found. Please check data entry and try again.");
        }
        return -1;
    }

    //method that sorts student's grades for a specific course in descending order
    private void sort()
    {
        //storing used nodes in temp Integer array which will be used
        //to compare and sort the grade values of each node
        Integer[] usedNodes = new Integer[numStudents];

        for (int i = list, j = 0; i != NUL; i = nodes[i].next)
        {
            usedNodes[j++] = i;
        }

        //sorting the temp array in descending order using custom
        //comparator and Arrays.sort from Java.util.Arrays.
        Arrays.sort(usedNodes, (i1, i2) ->
        {
            return Float.compare(nodes[i2].grade, nodes[i1].grade);
        });

        //rebuilding the linked list after sorting
        list = usedNodes[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < usedNodes.length; i++)
        {
            nodes[usedNodes[i-1]].next = usedNodes[i];
        }
        nodes[usedNodes[usedNodes.length - 1]].next = NUL;
    }
//Determines whether this list is full
    public boolean isFull()
    {
        return (free == NUL);
    }

    //prints grades for a specific course. Calls sort()
    //method before printing
    public void printData()
    {
        current = list;
        while (current != NUL)
        {
            sort();
            System.out.println(nodes[current].toString());
            previous = current;
            current = nodes[current].next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try [`Arrays.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-)? No need to implement your own sorting algorithm.

Comment: I was under the impression it wouldn't work for this given implementation, but you think it would be worth a shot?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** Original answer assumed that you just wanted to sort the list after the fact, but looking closer, it appears you want to insert sorted, where Students with same grade should be in insert order.

To do that, the `addStudentGrade()` method needs to be mostly replaced. Instead of "sorting", you search for "insert point", and add the new node there.

To show this, I've reduced the code to be an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example). You can see full code on [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/6jJeek).

```
public void addStudentGrade(Object stu, float grade) {
    // Search for insertion point (i.e. between prevIdx and nextIdx)
    int prevIdx = NUL;
    int nextIdx = list;
    while (nextIdx != NUL && nodes[nextIdx].grade >= grade) {
        prevIdx = nextIdx;
        nextIdx = nodes[nextIdx].next;
    }

    // Initialize and insert new node
    int newIdx = getNode();
    nodes[newIdx].student = stu;
    nodes[newIdx].grade = grade;
    nodes[newIdx].next = nextIdx;
    if (prevIdx == NUL)
        list = newIdx;
    else
        nodes[prevIdx].next = newIdx;
}
```

---

**Original Answer**

That is a really weird class, with a index-based linked list into a fixed-size array of nodes.

I'd suggest, that to sort the non-free nodes, you start by collecting those nodes in an array, or rather their node indexes. Since you know how many in-use nodes you have, i.e. `numStudents`, create a new array of that size, then fill it with the indexes of the in-use nodes. Note that the array must be `Integer[]`, not `int[]`, so a custom Comparator can be supplied for the sorting:

```
Integer[] inuse = new Integer[numStudents];
for (int i = list, j = 0; i != NUL; i = nodes[i].next)
    inuse[j++] = i;
```

Then sort them using a custom `Comparator`, e.g. using Java 8 lambda:

```
Arrays.sort(inuse, (i1, i2) -> {
    return Float.compare(nodes[i2].grade, nodes[i1].grade); // descending
});
```

Now that they are sorted, you need to re-build the linked list:

```
list = inuse[0];
for (int j = 1; j < inuse.length; j++)
    nodes[inuse[j - 1]].next = inuse[j];
nodes[inuse[inuse.length - 1]].next = NUL;
```

I believe that should do it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate the input! I tried another sorting algorithm before you posted this and it didn't work either. I agree it is a very strange class, but its how I was instructed to implement the design.

Comment: Hmm, the list still isn't sorting correctly. Functionality has definitely improved, but the grades are sorted based on the order they came in. I sincerely appreciate your input, if you get the chance to look over this with me again I would be forever grateful. Thanks again, Andreas :)

Comment: I actually went with your original implementation w a couple tweaks of my own. Instead of sorting on each addition, I instead made a method sort() and I call that every time the display method is called. seems to be working great so far! Seriously, thanks a bunch. Your code is quite elegant :) Took me a minute to wrap my head around it, but once I did it was really intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

I think your real problem is a misinterpretation of requirements, respectively an insufficient data model.

What I mean is: your student class should be knowing about grades. For example a student object could contain a map of grades (where the keys might represent the different courses). And of course, there is only one student object per real student.

And now you would put the same student into different arrays/lists, and you sort always that one list, based on whatever criteria is appropriate. As long story short your idea of sorting arrays of nodes just creates a conceptual confusion.

What I am saying is: there is no point in keeping the members of a course sorted this way. A course simply knows how many seats are available. So when adding a student, you only worry if that course is full or not.

And then a course might have the feature of listing the enrolled students; using whatever sort criteria you want.

Those are two completely independent "use cases" and you should avoid mangling them together.

Comment: I ABSOLUTELY agree with you there, but this is how I was instructed to implement the program by my professor(who has a history of questionable instructions). Alas, I still need to sort the nodes by their float grade values...  EDIT: This is a very small part of a much, much larger implementation, so some things may seem dubious because of this.

Comment: I appreciate the input. There is indeed an enrollment portion of my program that ties in this Course class, so it does make some sense when seeing the whole picture. It's not the greatest implementation, I know. I'll keep trying though, thanks :)